# How to dynamically set the field in Mongoose when doing aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
someModel.aggregate([{
                        $group: {_id:null,
                         average:{$avg:"$low"}}
                    }
                    ])
```

in the above code "low" is a field where i want to perform average.but am having some more fields too.
when i get the value of field i cant dynamically set it. i need to use if/else like below to achieve this.

```
if(field==="low"){
      someModel.aggregate([{
                            $group: {_id:null,
                             average:{$avg:"$low"}}}])
}else if(field==="high"){
     someModel.aggregate([{
                            $group: {_id:null,
                             average:{$avg:"$high"}}}])
}
```

is this the only way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to concatenate that using `field` variable:

```js
let field = 'low';
let group = {  $group: {_id:null,
                             average:{$avg:"$" + field}}};

console.log(group);
```

```
someModel.aggregate([group]);
```